# hiding of existing error message when retyping credentials

Tags: jquery

`LoginScreen.prototype.loginError = function(objData) 
{
      this.objActivity.hidePreloader();
      this.objActivity.$el.find('#error-                                       msg').text(JSON.parse(objData.responseText).StatusMessage).parent().show();
};`

and now I want to hide this error message ,whenever I retype my credentials

Comment: Posting some of your HTML would help. What is `$el`? What is `#error-msg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the on focus event to clear all error-msgs

```
$("#yourfieldtext").focus(function() {
  ('#error-msg').text("");
});
```

Hope this can help.